# Node.JS Nodemailer using long HTML

Tags: html, css, node.js, nodemailer

I have a problem.
I'm using Node.JS nodemailer.

```
const url = `${url}`;
var mailOptions = {

    from: 'stackoverflow',
    to: email,
    subject: 'test',
    html: 'Please click this email to confirm your email: <a href="${url}">${url}</a>`'
};
```

The HTML is quite long. So I would have to link each line with

'Line1' +

'Line2' +

and unfortunately the uplines are shown an error see: align = 'center'

Is there a way to embed this HTML file simply and easily?
And if I can include the file separately I have created a variable and this should then be displayed in HTML. How would that work?
Can I somehow embed the file differently than directly in the code? I appreciate help!

This is my html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>[SUBJECT]</title>
      <style type="text/css">
      body {
       padding-top: 0 !important;
       padding-bottom: 0 !important;
       padding-top: 0 !important;
       padding-bottom: 0 !important;
       margin:0 !important;
       width: 100% !important;
       -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
       -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
       -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
     }
     .tableContent img {
       border: 0 !important;
       display: block !important;
       outline: none !important;
     }
     a{
      color:#382F2E;
    }

    p, h1{
      color:#382F2E;
      margin:0;
    }
 p{
      text-align:left;
      color:#999999;
      font-size:14px;
      font-weight:normal;
      line-height:19px;
    }

    a.link1{
      color:#382F2E;
    }
    a.link2{
      font-size:16px;
      text-decoration:none;
      color:#ffffff;
    }

    h2{
      text-align:left;
       color:#222222; 
       font-size:19px;
      font-weight:normal;
    }
    div,p,ul,h1{
      margin:0;
    }

    .bgBody{
      background: #ffffff;
    }
    .bgItem{
      background: #ffffff;
    }
    
@media only screen and (max-width:480px)
        
{
        
table[class="MainContainer"], td[class="cell"] 
    {
        width: 100% !important;
        height:auto !important; 
    }
td[class="specbundle"] 
    {
        width:100% !important;
        float:left !important;
        font-size:13px !important;
        line-height:17px !important;
        display:block !important;
        padding-bottom:15px !important;
    }
        
td[class="spechide"] 
    {
        display:none !important;
    }
        img[class="banner"] 
    {
              width: 100% !important;
              height: auto !important;
    }
        td[class="left_pad"] 
    {
            padding-left:15px !important;
            padding-right:15px !important;
    }
         
}
    
@media only screen and (max-width:540px) 

{
        
table[class="MainContainer"], td[class="cell"] 
    {
        width: 100% !important;
        height:auto !important; 
    }
td[class="specbundle"] 
    {
        width:100% !important;
        float:left !important;
        font-size:13px !important;
        line-height:17px !important;
        display:block !important;
        padding-bottom:15px !important;
    }
        
td[class="spechide"] 
    {
        display:none !important;
    }
        img[class="banner"] 
    {
              width: 100% !important;
              height: auto !important;
    }
    .font {
        font-size:18px !important;
        line-height:22px !important;
        
        }
        .font1 {
        font-size:18px !important;
        line-height:22px !important;
        
        }
}

    </style>
<script type="colorScheme" class="swatch active">
{
    "name":"Default",
    "bgBody":"ffffff",
    "link":"382F2E",
    "color":"999999",
    "bgItem":"ffffff",
    "title":"222222"
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body paddingwidth="0" paddingheight="0"   style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; background-repeat: repeat; width: 100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;" offset="0" toppadding="0" leftpadding="0">
    <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tableContent" align="center"  style='font-family:Helvetica, Arial,serif;'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="MainContainer">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" width="40">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
  <!-- =============================== Header ====================================== -->   
    <tr>
        <td height='75' class="spechide"></td>
        
        <!-- =============================== Body ====================================== -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='movableContentContainer ' valign='top'>
        <div class="movableContent" style="border: 0px; padding-top: 0px; position: relative;">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="35"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="center" class="specbundle"><div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable">
                                <div class="contentEditable">
                                  <p style='text-align:center;margin:0;font-family:Georgia,Time,sans-serif;font-size:26px;color:#222222;'><span class="specbundle2"><span class="font1">Welcome to&nbsp;</span></span></p>
                                </div>
                              </div></td>
      <td valign="top" class="specbundle"><div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable">
                                <div class="contentEditable">
                                  <p style='text-align:center;margin:0;font-family:Georgia,Time,sans-serif;font-size:26px;color:#DC2828;'><span class="font">[CLIENTS.COMPANY_NAME]</span> </p>
                                </div>
                              </div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
        <div class="movableContent" style="border: 0px; padding-top: 0px; position: relative;">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                          <tr>
                            <td valign='top' align='center'>
                              <div class="contentEditableContainer contentImageEditable">
                                <div class="contentEditable">
                                  <img src="images/line.png" width='251' height='43' alt='' data-default="placeholder" data-max-width="560">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="movableContent" style="border: 0px; padding-top: 0px; position: relative;">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                          <tr><td height='55'></td></tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align='left'>
                              <div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable">
                                <div class="contentEditable" align='center'>
                                  <h2 >Will this be your welcome email?</h2>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr><td height='15'> </td></tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td align='left'>
                              <div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable">
                                <div class="contentEditable" align='center'>
                                  <p >
                                    Here’s what you can say: Thanks again for signing up to the newsletter! You’re all set up, and will be getting the emails once per week. Meanwhile, you can check out our <a target='_blank' href='#' class='link1' >Getting Started</a> section to get the most out of your new account. 
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    Have questions? Get in touch with us via Facebook or Twitter, or email our support team.
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    Cheers,
                                    <br>
                                    <span style='color:#222222;'>Peter Parker</span>
                                  </p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr><td height='55'></td></tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td align='center'>
                              <table>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align='center' bgcolor='#1A54BA' style='background:#DC2828; padding:15px 18px;-webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;'>
                                    <div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable">
                                      <div class="contentEditable" align='center'>
                                        <a target='_blank' href='#' class='link2' style='color:#ffffff;'>Activate your Account</a>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr><td height='20'></td></tr>
                        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="movableContent" style="border: 0px; padding-top: 0px; position: relative;">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height='65'>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  style='border-bottom:1px solid #DDDDDD;'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td height='25'></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="specbundle"><div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable">
                                      <div class="contentEditable" align='center'>
                                        <p  style='text-align:left;color:#CCCCCC;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;line-height:20px;'>
                                          <span style='font-weight:bold;'>[CLIENTS.COMPANY_NAME]</span>
                                          <br>
                                          [CLIENTS.ADDRESS]
                                          <br>
                                          <a target='_blank' href="[FORWARD]">Forward to a friend</a><br>
                                          <a target="_blank" class='link1' class='color:#382F2E;' href="[UNSUBSCRIBE]">Unsubscribe</a>
                                          <br>
                                          <a target='_blank' class='link1' class='color:#382F2E;' href="[SHOWEMAIL]">Show this email in your browser</a>
                                        </p>
                                      </div>
                                    </div></td>
      <td valign="top" width="30" class="specbundle">&nbsp;</td>
      <td valign="top" class="specbundle"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign='top' width='52'>
                                    <div class="contentEditableContainer contentFacebookEditable">
                                      <div class="contentEditable">
                                        <a target='_blank' href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" width='52' height='53' alt='facebook icon' data-default="placeholder" data-max-width="52" data-customIcon="true"></a>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
      <td valign="top" width="16">&nbsp;</td>
      <td valign='top' width='52'>
                                    <div class="contentEditableContainer contentTwitterEditable">
                                      <div class="contentEditable">
                                        <a target='_blank' href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width='52' height='53' alt='twitter icon' data-default="placeholder" data-max-width="52" data-customIcon="true"></a>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td height='88'></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

        </div>
        
      
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td>
      <td valign="top" width="40">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply keep your template-html in a file and use an arbitrary js-templating library (e.g. [ejs](https://ejs.co)) to parse the template data and render its `html`. Something like this should help you get started:

In your `app.js` do the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const eis = require('ejs');

const template = fs.readFileSync("/path/to/your/template.ejs");
const templateData = { url:  `${url}`, otherDataYouNeedToSetInTemplate: "here" };  
const renderedHtml = ejs.render(template, templateData};

const mailOptions = {

    from: 'stackoverflow',
    to: email,
    subject: 'test',
    html: renderedHtml
};
```

Then in your `template.ejs` you can access the properties from `templateData` and set its values in the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
....
Please click this email to confirm your email: <a href="<%= url %>"><%= url %></a>`
....
</html>
```